# ESR Half Field Transition

Tags: angular-momentum, atomic-physics, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

I am studying ESR with Atherton.

While reading the book, I found something weird (at least to me). Can anyone help me with this?

[image]

What I know is that $M_S = 2$ transitions can occur because at low fields, the eigenstates are the mixture of Zeeman eigenstates.

[image]

But when $E = 0$ and field lies along $Z$, our Hamiltonian is diagonalized even at low fields. This means that the eigenstates are not the mixture of Zeeman eigenstates, which also means that there can never be $M_S = 2$ transition.

But why is the book saying, "when $E = 0$, $M_S = 2$ transition occur exactly half the value of $M_S = 1 $?"

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.